# Can´t store Unicode characters on SQL Azure for Mobile Services

Tags: sql, linq, azure, unicode, azure-mobile-services

I´m using Windows Azure Mobile Services with a SQL Azure database, for my Windows Phone 8 App.

**I´m trying to store strings that contains Unicode characters**, in concrete, **emojis like  `⛅`**  ,etc...

But **in the SQL Azure explorer, I always see a simbol with '?'** (�). I have declared this Col. as `Nvarchar(max).`

To insert the row with the string field, I´m using the function: `await Table.InsertAsync(Register)`.

The Collation of the Database is: `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`

**Why I can´t save and retrieve these Unicode characters??** I thought with Nvarchar, all Unicode strings would be allowed.

Thanks.

Comment: When I retrieve the string from the Database, my App obtains the symbol '?' that is in Azure. Also I don´t know why using local SQL database with Isolated Storage, it works fine and I can retrieve these characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently a bug in the runtime in which it cannot handle Unicode characters beyond the codepoint 0x10000 (in C#, they'd be represented by a pair of Unicode surrogate chars). That's the region where many Emoji characters are located. I had this problem in a PoC which I was working on a while back, and I worked around it by encoding such characters on the client side. I don't have the code now, but I was using something similar to the code below:

```
public class MyType
{
    private string value;
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < this.value.Length; i++)
            {
                if (this.value[i] == '\\')
                {
                    if (i < this.value.Length - 1 && this.value[i + 1] == '\\')
                    {
                        sb.Append('\\');
                        i++;
                    }
                    else if (i < this.value.Length - 5 && this.value[i + 1] == 'u')
                    {
                        sb.Append((char)Convert.ToInt32(this.value.Substring(i + 2, 4), 16));
                        i += 5;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid encoding");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(this.value[i]);
                }
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var c in value)
            {
                if (c == '\\')
                {
                    sb.Append("\\\\");
                }
                else if (Char.IsSurrogate(c))
                {
                    sb.AppendFormat("\\u{0:X4}", (int)c);
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(c);
                }
            }

            this.value = sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

This definitely doesn't have the best performance (lots of [un]escaping when accessing a property), but it wasn't a bit bottleneck in my case. Another alternative would be to implement the escaping / unescaping in a message handler, so that in the normal usage of a data type (i.e., accessing its properties) such perf hit won't be felt (only when going over the network, and that would likely be the bottleneck instead of the conversions).